# If $N\equiv 1\pmod 4$ does then follow that $p\equiv q\equiv 1\pmod 4$

Tags: prime-numbers

$N = pq$ is the product of two primes.

If $N\equiv 1\pmod 4$, does then follow that $p\equiv q\equiv 1\pmod 4$ ?

Comment: $3\times 7 = 21$ - not too hard to check a few values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't. For $p\equiv q\equiv 3\pmod 4$, $pq\equiv 9\equiv 1\pmod 4$.

Since $p,q\equiv 1,2,3\pmod 4$, one has$$pq\equiv 1\pmod 4\iff p\equiv q\equiv 1\ \ \text{or}\ \ p\equiv q\equiv 3\pmod 4.$$

Comment: Can you without factoring find out if p = q = 1 mod 4 or p = q  = 3 mod 4?

Comment: but i don't know p and q?

Comment: @testboy: I do not know a computationally efficient way for very large $N$. Interesting question!

Comment: @testboy: Ah, sorry I misunderstood what you meant. I think it's difficult... All I can say is that p=q=1 or p=q=3.

Comment: is this a general rule that if:  p = k mod h and q = g mod h is then pq = gk mod h

Comment: @testboy: Yes, it is. Proof : Since there exist integers $a,b$ such that $p=ha+k,q=hb+g$, one has $pq=(ha+k)(hb+g)=h(hab+ag+kb)+gk\equiv gk\pmod h$.